# How i can resolve "identity iPhone developer: my name(*) Does not match any valid ,Non Expired certificate/Private key pair in our keychains"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I am Facing problem during  test apps  in device  and problem is :

"identity iPhone developer: my  name(*) Does not match any valid ,Non Expired certificate/Private key pair in our keychains"

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid, non-expired iPhone Developer cert in your keychain (with associated private key)? If this problem just showed up, your certificate may have expired.

Comment: i am also follow this step :You dont need a separate private key.

Make sure the bundle identifier in your build settings matches that of the provision profile, the profile which was signed with the certificate that you have in your keychain.
  but still i am getting solution please help me.

Comment: you need a valid Provisioning Profile, Developer Identity (Certificate & Private Key) and a valid App ID that is registered in Provisioning Portal if you implement APNS, iCloud, Passes, Game Center or iAd.

Comment: Hello kevin , ya i am sure ,  i got this message.can u suggest what is exact solution.

Comment: hello shivan , i see certificate  its valid and its show green check mark in keychains .

Answer (score 0):

This is a certificate error.Kindly delete the development certifivet from your keychain,Download it again from your itunes account and install again.
Also check weather you are using correct provisioning